# Wave pulse generation

Tags: waves

When two different strings of different mass per unit lengths ( mass per unit length of lower one being less than the upper string) are joined and are hanged vertically and pulse is generated at the bottom end then how does the speed of the wave pulse change at the the junction of the two ropes?

Comment: what is your view please share some of your efforts!

Comment: The speed of the wave pulse will be different in both the strings. To calculate the speed in the two cases , Tension per unit length is required. What i am really confused about is whether the mass of the lower string will be included in the calculation done on the upper part or not?

Comment: how do you define tension in a string at an element ?  it is obviously the mass it supports  isnt it !

Comment: So in the calculation of the upper part, the lower string will just be treated as a mass hanging down the string?

Comment: i think this is right

Comment: So in the upper part of the string, as a known mass is assumed to be hanging down, the tension will be a constant and will not vary with the length. Am i right?

Comment: nope that is not right say at a length x from the bottom the mass hanging is equivalent to mxg/l considering just a simple  case of a rope hanging